# PHP Cron Job does not give correct directory path

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP module that is in my public_html directory (for example mycronjob.php)

If i execute **mycronjob.php** from the browser it works as it should.

> For example the command `getcwd()` gives /home/myaccount/public_html
>   and all fopen commands open files in public_html.

However, if I execute exactly the same module as a cron job the command
getcwd() gives /home/myaccount
and all fopen commands open files in myaccount instead of public_html

The Cron Job is :
`/usr/local/bin/php -e /home/myaccount/public_html/mycronjob.php`

Does anyone have any idea why the cron job **getcwd()** and **fopen()**
commands would not be resolving to public_html ?
My Host seems to be struggling to find the cause.

A typical **fopen()** command is:

```
$myfile='mydata.htm';
if(($myfile = fopen($myfile,'w')) === FALSE){
echo "Failed to open myfile file for writing!" . "<br />\n";
exit(8);
}
```

Comment: The script is being executed from your user's local directory, not the public_html dir. Potentially http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php to the public directory if it currently is not...assuming you have permissions

Answer (score 3):

It's because of where the cron gets executed from. It's pretty normal and you can fix it by using the **FILE** constant.

`$file = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'mydata.htm';`